# How to get key in loop slice in text/template?

Tags: go

For example

```
{{ range $k, $v := .rec}}
{{ $k }} :: {{ $v }}
{{ end }}
```

Catch error `panic: template: let:2:19: executing "let" at <.rec>: can't evaluate field rec in type []string`.

Comment: Well, `.rec` tries to access an unexported fields, so that's to expect (and has nothing to do with the loop). Also: probably you got your data types wrong.

Answer (score -1):

```
{{ range $k, $v := .}}
{{ $k }} :: {{ $v }}
{{ end }}
```